# Button containing images and text

Tags: android

I have to create a small panel like thing with a border.
This should contain a text, an image that describes the text and a button.
On clicking that button I have to do some operations also.
Which widget is suitable for this?
Can anyone suggests any idea?

Answer (score 0):

ImageButton is what I can think of. Try the ApiDemo sample application comes up with android sdk too. Another tool you might need is DroidDraw (Free android UI designer) and hierarchyviewer.bat(inside android sdk tools) can also help you if you want to know how the other developers use for such purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed that you want to display button with images + Text,

You can do it with Button. There are 2 ways to do it(Button with Image and Text).

- By xml, you can set
  `android:background` attribute of
  button and the text which you set,
  will be appeared above the
  background.
- By code, You can use
  `setBackgroundDrawable()` , it is
  used to set the background of a
  button.

and If you want to display panel(By clicking on the handle of that panel, it will comes up with the many items as home screen) , `slidingDrawer` widgets is the best solution.